# Xamarin and MVVMCross - EmployeeDirectory

Tags: mvvmcross

Xamarin.Android has a nice little demo called EmployeeDirectory. I am looking forward to implemenmt the PersonActivity in MVVMX. This activity is basically a listview that takes arbitrary data from the VM, and display them in grouped mode.

I have fiddled with the Grouped listview in MVVMx Conference example and got this to work. This is as close as what I am looking for. Would there be any MVVMx example that mimics the EmployeeDirectory PersonActivity page? http://xamarin.com/prebuilt/employeedirectory

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for samples of ListView, you may want to look at some of the N+1 Videos, specifically Books(N-06 - N-07), Kittens(N-10 - N-11), and CollectABull(N-12 - N-17)

N+1 MvvmCross
https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross

MvvmCross Tutorials
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials

For example:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-06-Books/Books.Droid/Resources/Layout/FirstView.axml

```
    <Mvx.MvxListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Results" 
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_book"
    />
```

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He6QvnLsPUA

Comment: I believe I have found suitable example in mvvmx, except that the example is not running. The 'working with collections' seems to do what I want. I am giving it a try.